# execute a script from a script failing respect white

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, whitespace

I'm trying to run a script from a script with the exec command, but are having problems with it, I think it's handling the arguments as one Argument.

I've tried

```
exec  $0 -r -c -i $instance -s $sdir -d $ddir

exec  "$0 -r -c -i $instance -s $sdir -d $ddir"

exec  '$0 -r -c -i $instance -s $sdir -d $ddir'
```

but none of them are working correctly

I've read about white spaces, and as I understand it, the first one should work

Comment: `exec "$0" -r -c -i "$instance" -s "$sdir" -d "$ddir"`. Are you sure you want `$0` and not `$1`?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I want to script to reload itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one should work, but as @jordanm suggests, always put variables inside double quote "", to prevent spaces and special characters mess with your code

`exec "$0" -r -c -i "$instance" -s "$sdir" -d "$ddir"`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I actually wrote the wrong variable $instance should be $instancenr..